How can i assign a VM in Azure to view all subscriptions using Managed Identity?
I have a VM in Azure i have assigned an Identity and i can login using
 az login --identity

When i do that , it only displays the Subscription that the VM is in .
I have a number of subscriptions and I want that VM to be able to view all subscriptions and be able to access all resources in all subscriptions .
I have tried to configure Role assignment but couldnt see anything that would allow the VM to access all subscriptions
How can i configure the VM identity to access all subscriptions and all resources ?


How can i assign a VM in Azure to view all subscriptions using Managed Identity?

To assign a role to the VM identity on different subscriptions, follow these steps

Enable the VM Identity by navigating to Virtual Machines > Identity.



Assign the role to another subscription in same tenant, by navigating to another Subscription > Access control (IAM) > Add role assignment > Select the role > User, group, or service principal > Enter your VM Name at search place.


Note:  If you select Managed identity, The managed identity will be access within the same subscription, it won't display in another subscription

.


Once assign the roles to the VM identity, when I try to log in with the identity, I am able to see all subscription details which are assigned, as shown below.

Output:


so if you have lets say 10 subscription , you must add it in all 10 ?

Yes, you need to provided access all 10 subscriptions.
